# Blender baking problem

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I'm following this [article](http://cg.tutsplus.com/tutorials/blender/creating-a-low-poly-ninja-game-character-using-blender-uvmapping-and-texturing/) about texturing a model. I'm already in step 30 but when I baked my model, I get these holes between the neck and chest. What causes this?

**Edit:**
Even when not baking and just setting the shading to smooth, shows this odd faces (3rd picture). I think its because of how I connected the neck to the body. Any tips on how should I correct this?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site animel. I don't understand what holes you mean. Could you explain some more? Another thing is that you should set shading to smooth before baking (to get rid of the sharp lines in your bake). In object mode click smooth in the toolbar to the left.

Comment: Hi, what I mean the holes are the missing faces just below the neck when I render in texture mode. See second picture. I also selected those in the first picture to specify.

Thank you for the info about setting the shading to smooth to get rid of the sharp lines. I thought it's because of the topology. I actually wasted hours redoing the model. :D

Comment: As you probably notice, the problem with inverted normals is way easier to spot if you turn on smooth shading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because the normals of the faces got turned upside down, so backfacing was making them invisible in textured view.

All I had to do is recalculate the normals: <kbd>Tab</kbd>*> Edit mode >* <kbd>A</kbd>*> Select all >* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>*> Recalculate normals*.

Comment: Then you may also mark this as the answer to your own question.

Comment: Yes, but only after 2 days after posting the question.